# mybb posts and responses counter

Tags: forum, forums, mybb

how to changes mybb posts and responses counter text in MYBB forum to another custom message

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked within MyBB Admin to see if it's something in the template you can change?

If not it could be something in the language file, found in /inc/languages/

Not entirely sure what it is you're trying to changed

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you are unable to directly edit the posts unless going into the MySQL database and manually changing it. 
However be careful, MyBB isn't as simple as it seems!

Comment: This is more a comment then a actual answer

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it in global.lang.php present inside MyBB langauge folder.
`$l['forumbit_threads'] = "Threads";`
`$l['forumbit_posts'] = "Posts";`

Change Threads or Posts to anything you want.

Cheers